# label background and foreground change Unexpectedly

Tags: asp.net, css, web-applications

In my web applicaton I have some div that contain labels, when I click on a label it's foreground become blue and background become white.how can I prevent that?

Comment: Can you show just the html markup that demonstrates the issue? Isn't it just default behavior of the browser indicating you're selecting the content?

Comment: I solve it by using this right now:label { background-color:transparent;}
label:focus{ background-color:transparent;}
label:hover { background-color:transparent;}
label::selection { background-color:transparent;}
label:double-button { background-color:transparent;}
label { background-color: transparent; -moz-user-select: none; -webkit-user-select: none; -ms-user-select: none; user-select: none; }

I don't know which line is really Necessary. but it works

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid disabling user select colours. I don't know about other people but I often select text on websites, not because I want to copy it but because I am struggling to read it and selecting text is by far the easiest way to change the colour of text against it's background. I even sometimes do it with black text on a white background.